# Grad-cam problem

Tags: keras, visualization

I have the method given below and the model shown in the picture. What layers do I need to use for the grad-cam process?

```
def make_gradcam_heatmap(
img_array, model, last_conv_layer_name, classifier_layer_names):
last_conv_layer = model.get_layer(last_conv_layer_name)
last_conv_layer_model = keras.Model(model.inputs, last_conv_layer.output)

last_conv_layer_model.summary()

classifier_input = keras.Input(shape=last_conv_layer.output.shape[1:])
x = classifier_input
for layer_name in classifier_layer_names:
    x = model.get_layer(layer_name)(x)
classifier_model = keras.Model(classifier_input, x)

with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
    # Compute activations of the last conv layer and make the tape watch it
    last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_model(img_array)
    tape.watch(last_conv_layer_output)
    # Compute class predictions
    preds = classifier_model(last_conv_layer_output)
    top_pred_index = tf.argmax(preds[0])
    top_class_channel = preds[:, top_pred_index]


grads = tape.gradient(top_class_channel, last_conv_layer_output)

pooled_grads = tf.reduce_mean(grads, axis=(0, 1, 2))

last_conv_layer_output = last_conv_layer_output.numpy()[0]
pooled_grads = pooled_grads.numpy()
for i in range(pooled_grads.shape[-1]):
    last_conv_layer_output[:, :, i] *= pooled_grads[i]

heatmap = np.mean(last_conv_layer_output, axis=-1)

heatmap = np.maximum(heatmap, 0) / np.max(heatmap)
return heatmap

last_conv_layer_name = 'global_average_pooling2d_1'
classifier_layer_names = ['dense_8' ,'dense_9' ] 
image= get_input(r'k019005062.jpg' )  
heatmap = make_gradcam_heatmap(image, model, last_conv_layer_name, classifier_layer_names)
```

[image]

Comment: is there anyone who can help?
here are the codes
[https://www.kaggle.com/mervearmagan/gradcamproblem](https://www.kaggle.com/mervearmagan/gradcamproblem)